# How to log nested input element value without needing its ID?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I'm trying to select the value of an input box from a user generated ordered list of text boxes, and further log its value to the console. I haven't been able to find a way to select the value of a child's child element, in which the IDs are unknown. Currently I keep getting this console error:

```
cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="processing.php" method="post">
    <ol id="spawnList"> 
    </ol>
    <button type="button" id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly();">Add</button>
    <button type="button" name="submit" onClick="sub_strings()">Save</button>
</form>
```

This is an example list element that a user would generate:

```
<li id="465817232" class="1" index="1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="465817232" class="1" index="1">
    <button type="button" onclick="redirect()" id="465817232" class="1" index="1">Edit</button>
    <button id="465817232" onclick="removeElement(this.id)" class="1" index="1">Delete</button>
</li>
```

This is my JS function:

```
    function sub_strings()
    {
        var printer = document.getElementById("spawnList").getElementsByTagName["LI"].getElementsByTagName["INPUT"].item[1];
        console.log(printer)
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're thinking that those attributes from an element are arrays, however, those "attributes" are functions which return "arrays" (actually return objects which could be treated as arrays).

I recommend you to use functions like `.querySelector` and/or `.querySelectorAll` which use selectors.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#spawnList li input')).forEach(input => {
  console.log(input.id);
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="processing.php" method="post">
  <ol id="spawnList">
    <li id="465817232" class="1" index="1">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="465817232" class="1" index="1">
      <button type="button" onclick="redirect()" id="465817232" class="1" index="1">Edit</button>
      <button id="465817232" onclick="removeElement(this.id)" class="1" index="1">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <button type="button" id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly();">Add</button>
  <button type="button" name="submit" onClick="sub_strings()">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have read the DOM not yet created. The li tags are dynamically generated.
You should use the Jquery library with .on () to implement

```
$(document).on("click","#spawnList",function() {
  // TODO
});
```